# NameVirtualHost bad behavior on 2 IPs and 3 DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd

I have the next apache virtualhosts and NameVirtualHost settings:

```
NameVirtualHost 10.100.106.89

<VirtualHost 10.100.106.89>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev/novared_soporte/branches/v0.3/soporte
        ServerName 10.100.106.89
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.100.106.89>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
        ServerName 10.100.106.89/phpmyadmin
        ServerAlias 10.100.106.89/pma
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.100.106.90>
        ServerName 10.100.106.90
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to reach: `10.100.106.89` I can get to the site that I need: `/var/www/html/dev/novared_soporte/branches/v0.3/soporte`

but when I try to reach `10.100.106.89/phpmyadmin` I actually get this error on error_log.txt (httpd logs):

`[Thu Jun 28 12:12:59 2012] [error] [client 10.100.103.31] File does not exist: /var/www/html/dev/novared_soporte/branches/v0.3/soporte/phpmyadmin`

I still cant get where is the mistake. By the way, `10.100.106.90` is working properly, at least for its `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`

Answer (score 2):

you stated the DocumentRoot for 10.100.106.89 twice, you have to use an alias for phpmyadmin

```
NameVirtualHost 10.100.106.89
<VirtualHost 10.100.106.89>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev/novared_soporte/branches/v0.3/soporte
        ServerName 10.100.106.89
        Alias /phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin    
        #you need to explicitly allow access, since your alias is outside of your document root
        <Directory /var/www/html/phpmyadmin>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.100.106.90>
        ServerName 10.100.106.90
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

This will only allow access via 10.100.106.89/phpmyadmin, no other virtual hosts.

This is perhaps a solution, best to just use the Include directive to include the apache that come with phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a server name consist of anything other than a FQDN - don't put a `/` in it - it simply won't be interpreted.

Consider doing this, then just adding a HOSTS file entry instead

```
<VirtualHost 10.100.106.89>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev/novared_soporte/branches/v0.3/soporte
    ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.100.106.89>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
    ServerName phpmyadmin.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in your HOSTS file add

```
10.100.106.89 www.example.com
10.100.106.89 phpmyadmin.example.com
```

You can freely use `example.com` as per the [IETF guidelines](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606)

Or combine the two `vhosts` into a single `vhost`

```
<VirtualHost 10.100.106.89>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev/novared_soporte/branches/v0.3/soporte
    ServerName 10.100.106.89 
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Alias /phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define a IP address as a NameVirtualHost, the apache server is expecting the browser to pass the domain domain associated with that host to determine which document root to serve.

An example would be something like:

```
NameVirtualHost 10.100.106.89

<VirtualHost 10.100.106.89>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev/novared_soporte/branches/v0.3/soporte
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.100.106.89>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
        ServerName phpmyadmin.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.100.106.90>
        ServerName 10.100.106.90
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Your apache will serve the first document root when a user visits mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com and the second phpmyadmin root when visiting phpmyadmin.mydomain.com. All 3 of those records would point to the same IP address. For any traffic that hits the same IP address without a matching ServerName or ServerAlias, it will default to the first VirtualHost.